# Highlighting the inner code blocks in Django Template Engine with django-pygmentify

Tags: python, django, markdown, template-engine, pygments

I'm using [django-pygmentify](https://pypi.org/project/django-pygmentify/) package in order to highlight my code blocks in my Django templates. The thing is that this package only supports code blocks as input. I have a model field that keeps markdown data. This markdown content might contain code blocks. (using ``` symbol)

Now, how can I highlight its inner code blocks??

Imagine I have a field that only contains source code. Like:

```
print('Hey..!')
```

In that case, this one works properly.

```html
{% load pygmentify_tags %}
...
{% pygmentify %}
{{post.code}}
{% endpygmentify %}
```

Imagine my field contains the following content.

````
## Hello
This is my first step working with Python.
```python
print('Hey..!')
‍```
````

In this case, how can I implement it?? I can render that whole markdown content with `{{post.body|markdown|safe}}`, but how can I highlight those code blocks?? I also want to give all those code blocks a class name `.code-block` for better styling. Should I create a custom template tag?

Answer (score 0):

You may use html standard `<code>` tag like this:

```
{% load pygmentify_tags %}
...
{% pygmentify %}
<code>
{{post.code}}
</code>
{% endpygmentify %}
```

This will separate the code section and at the same time will apply pygmentify to it.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, my problem is to highlight the code inside the markdown content. Thanks btw.